# Google Developer Console create new Entity error

Tags: entity, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a new Entity in the Google Developer Console Cloud Datastore, but whenever I try to create an Entity with more than one property I keep this error:

"The user request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again."

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error as well. I found that it was because I had a string property that I wanted to have the empty string in so I left the value blank. Apparently that's not allowed. I removed that property and was able to create the entity just fine.

I then went and edited the entity and added the property back in and gave it a value and saved it. This worked fine. Then I went and left the property there, but made the value field blank, and was able to save it just fine as well.

Glitch in the initial creation process maybe? Either way, I was able to create the entity I wanted with no extra data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error because there was an `_` in my URL. I was trying to configure OAuth for my subdomain. It worked after I removed the underscore from the subdomain.

Really odd that Google doesn't consider `_` to be valid in a URL string! (:mild_annoyance:)